# Error in getting the input in queryparam

Tags: java, sql, rest, param

I have a problem in my web service. It is because, on my first url path, it will check the plate number. Now, I want to get the input of the user from the first url path and use it on the second path. Is it possible? Here's the first url where I will scan the input of the user:

```
package com.taxisafe.server;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.taxisafe.connection.DatabaseConnection;
import com.taxisafe.json.JsonConstruction;


//PATH FOR CHECKING PLATE NUMBER

@Path("platecheck")  //for the url

public class PlateNumberCheck {
@GET 
//To get the full url : http://Ipaddress:portnumber/@path/@getPath 
@Path("/check")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
//Produces is for the response of JSON.

public String check(@QueryParam("platenumber") String platenumber){
String sagot = "";
if(checkInput(platenumber)){
    sagot = JsonConstruction.JSONResponse("checked", true);
} else{ 
    sagot = JsonConstruction.JSONResponse("checked", false, "Not in the database");
}
return sagot;
}

private boolean checkInput (String platenumber){
System.out.println("Check Input");
boolean output = false;
if(JsonConstruction.isNotNull(platenumber)){
    try{
        output = DatabaseConnection.checkPlate(platenumber);
    } catch (Exception e){
        output = false;
    }
} else{
    output = false;
}

return output; 
}   

}
```

Here is where I want to access the platenumber without using another String like taxi_plate_no

```
package com.taxisafe.server;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.taxisafe.array.ArrayConnection;
import com.taxisafe.connection.DatabaseConnection;
import com.taxisafe.json.JsonConstruction;
import com.taxisafe.objects.Objects;



@Path("/displays")
public class DisplayTaxiDetails {

@GET
@Path("taxidetails")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public String taxidetails(@QueryParam("taxi_plate_no") String taxi_plate_no{
    String sagot = "";
    String taxidetails = null;
    if(checkInput(taxi_plate_no)){
        sagot = JsonConstruction.JSONResponse("checked", true);
        ArrayList<Objects> taxiDetailsList = new ArrayList<Objects>();
        try{
            taxiDetailsList = new ArrayConnection().getTaxiDetails(taxi_plate_no);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            taxidetails = gson.toJson(taxiDetailsList);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return taxidetails;

    } else{ 
        sagot = JsonConstruction.JSONResponse("checked", false, "Not in the database");
    }
     return sagot;
    }

private boolean checkInput (String taxi_plate_no){
    System.out.println("Check Input");
    boolean output = false;
    if(JsonConstruction.isNotNull(taxi_plate_no)){
        try{
            output = DatabaseConnection.checkPlate(taxi_plate_no);
        } catch (Exception e){
            output = false;
        }
    } else{
        output = false;
    }

    return output;
}   

}
```

Comment: Maybe a better explanation of the _flow_ you are expecting. Right now your question doesn't make much sense, in terms of what exactly you expect/want to happen

Comment: Sorry, On the platenumbercheck class, there I want to get the plate number and check if it is in the database. Now, once it is in the database, it will display the array in the displataxidetails. I want to get platnumber inputted from the platenumbercheck and use it in displaytaxidetails.